# How to find segment with specific speed on the signal in comparison with reference signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, correlation

How do I find a segment on the signal where the signal speed is 2 times the speed of  the same segment on a reference signal?
Which features describe this?

On attached image can see "change of speed". Blue signal is reference, orange signal is measurement signal. Blue pen explain what I want find.

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming "speed" means "derivative"? In that case, I'm not sure what your circles are supposed to tell me, as the derivative is much higher in other regions... can you try to put your requirements in slightly more formalized words, or formulas, maybe?

Comment: I don’t know how to describe this. Basically I want to find patterns, marked with a blue circle in the orange signal.